# Maximizing Skype Sometimes Does not work properly

Tags: unity, skype, window

My problem is when I maximize Skype, it does not fully maximize the windows of Skype. There is an empty part in the screen.  Screenshot is shared [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV2iy.jpg). Notice that, this is supposed to be the maximum screen. However, it does not cover the whole screen. When I hold the top bar and drag the window to the top to maximize it, it fixes itself. I am writing here cause this situation also happens with other programs and it really disturbs me.

I could not find someone who had similar problem. Untill now I was able to find someone who had a similar problem and had a solution for other problems of mine. Thats why I am writing here. I am not willing to reinstall ubuntu cause my installation is relatively new. So thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Best Regards
Hsnbsrna